# Orphan Site Reported After Running Test-SPContentDatabase

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, sql-server, content-database

I'm upgrading from 2010 to 2013 and when I ran the Test-SPContentDatabase (on destination WFE server pointing at original content DB) command I got the following error relating to an orphan site:

```
Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = 
[8579eb01-ea17-4192-81e1-1e3aaba99aed], Url = [/]) whose url 
is already used by a different site, in database (Id = 
[d6fd0486-081e-4e0d-aba8-d8816b606a2d], name = 
[WSS_Content]), in the same web application. Consider 
deleting one of the sites which have conflicting urls.
```

Things I have tried:

- Detaching and attaching the content DB using PowerShell
- Running STSADM DatabaseRepair command
- Running STSADM Enumallwebs command

I prepped the new 2013 WFE server by creating a temp Web Application which uses Windows authentication (will convert to CBA post-upgrade). There is also a top level site collection on the 2013 server and I'm wondering if this is the cause? I have tried all the conventional approaches I can think of and checked similar questions here.

**UPDATE - 11/18/2013:**

I ran a SQL script on 2010 content DB to locate duplicate site [d6fd0486-081e-4e0d-aba8-d8816b606a2d] and got no results. When I ran it on the 2013 DB I got a result in the WSS_Content DatabaseInformation table which looks like the root site collection? Does this mean I should delete the destination 2013 site collection before proceeding with the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by deleting the site collection in the new SharePoint 2013 farm and confirmed this by running Test-SPContentDatabase again. The orphan site error was no longer being reported.

Answer (score 1):

Backup ContenteDB, remove contentDB in Central Admin, Mount the same contentDB and the problem is solved in my case. I have two issues, and this resolved both.